# MySQL : Sharing id's between public and private tables

Tags: mysql, sql, conflict, identifier

I'm modeling out a mysql database, but having problems with separating public vs private data.

The easiest way would be to have all the private and public data intermingled with each other, and just being able to recognize a piece of private data, by setting a 'isPrivate' bool to true - however I imagine this to be slow, and difficult to maintain.

So now I have two tables - private and public - but I want user's to be able to "publish" there private data as public data , to the public table.

The problem is with ID's - I can't have two different sets of ID's as the private and public rows are only really place holders to another table which holds the main data's content - if the private and public tables have different ID sets, there will be conflicts because I'm using an auto-increment ID naming scheme instead of just generating a hash, as it's less process intensive and there is no way of getting a "hash clash".

To solve the ID conflicts, the public data placeholder would have to change it's ID, which would make it lose it's reference to data it points to...

Is there a way in MySQL to only have a foreign key relate to only some of the ID's of a table, to another? that means I would be able to keep the same id's across both tables.

Maybe I could just sync the used ID to both tables through a function somehow? I'm no SQL wizkid thats for sure...

Also, again the public and private table's stores references to the actual data, which will be all inside one huge table. The public and private tables holds metadata for the main data - Is it possible to reference the public table metadata back to the original private metadata, and stop data duplication?

Thanks for your time,

Nathan.

Comment: Why is the `isPrivate` slower than the 2 table solution?

Comment: isPrivate is the way to go...two seperate tables is far more painful

Comment: For first, I would like the public data to have different meta then the private data - for example, how many people viewed the data, and rating of the data - the private table does not need this information - plus the Public data will be advertised in the front of the webapp - having public and private data in the same table, I would have to search through and prune the data - separating the public from the private. With them both in separate tables, I wouldn't have to do this extra comparison, thus being more performance friendly. I will look further into the offered solution however.

Comment: I'm not sure where you picked up the idea that a check on a boolean field is intensive/less performance friendly, its really not.  Two select statements from two different tables is far more...will you ever have a query that wants to look at both public and private data?  If you are really hurting for it...create a public and private 'view' that seperates the data.  Viewing/rating numbers can be stored in a seperate table that references this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to group all the entity data together and have clear maintenance. The public/private logic, access rights etc.. to achieve through the model in the main program. You can define private and public structures that program will use and so on... No one would actually need to know how this is handled on the database level

Also please consider using views to restrict access. Example: Create a view for an employee to see only his or her payroll information in a table that contains all employees.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have become rather light headed over these past few days. I could just create a foreign key between them. I seemed to think that when a table takes a foreign key of another it's coulomb is populated automatically - I don't know why I was thinking this...

Anyway - yes, use a foreign key.